# Accessing same variable across multiple classes with same value

Tags: android

I have two classes where I want to access the value of a unique variable.  In the first class I want to set the value of a 'isToogleflagon= true'.  In the second class I want to get the value of 'IsToogleflagon'.
Here is where I set and get 'IsToogleFlagon'

```
public class Toogleflag{
    private String _isToogleflagon;
    public Toogleflag(){}

    public  Toogleflag(String  isToogleflagon) {
            this._isToogleflagon=isToogleflagon;
            }

    public String get_isToogleflagon(){
          return _isToogleflagon; 
            }

    public void set_isToogleflagon(String isToogleflagon) {
           this._isToogleflagon = isToogleflagon;
             }
```

I want to set the value of isToogleflagon="true" in my main class.  Below is part of my main class where I do this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toogleflag toogleflag1 = new Toogleflag();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ... 
        toogleflag1.set_isToogleflagon(GlobalVariables.TRUE);
         ...
```

Global.values(True)

```
public class GlobalVariables
{
public static String TRUE = "true";
public static String FALSE = "false";
}
```

Here's my second class where I want to get the value of isToogleflagon, in this case "true"

```
 public class secondclass {
    Toogleflag toogleflag2 = new Toogleflag();

   public void test{

     String test=toogleflag2.get_isToogleflagon();
  }
```

When I run Class Secondclass the value of 'string test' does not get assigned a value. I want it to be assigned the value of "true".  Any advise on how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are making a new object with default/ no argument constructor. When you make an object with default constructor, all the instance variable gets initialzes with their default values. For example,

1) int variable gets **0**
2) boolean variable gets **false**
3) String variable gets **null**

That is happening in your case. As in your code it is mentioned that in main class when are you are setting value with String constructor to the variable named **isToogleflagon** it gets set as your constructor passed value, but when you are accessing the value of that variable again via calling no argument constructor, the variable **isToogleflagon** gets initiaze with defualt values as well. To get the value consistant across over all the app you need to make that class object as Singleton. It will be solving your problem. Hope you got my point. Below is the sample code for your reference to make singleton

```
public class Singleton {

   private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton( );

   /* A private Constructor prevents any other
    * class from instantiating.
    */
   private Singleton() { }

   /* Static 'instance' method */
   public static Singleton getInstance( ) {
  return singleton;
```

}

```
  /* Other methods protected by singleton-ness */
  protected static void demoMethod( ) {
  System.out.println("demoMethod for singleton");
  }
```

}

Comment: How would I apply this to my code?  Can you provide example?

Comment: just replace Singletone word with your class name and make methods in the class. Try like this if not succeded let me know

Comment: Ok, I think I got it to work.  So, to access the same 'singleton' across other classes I just create an instance of 'singleton' using the same variable.

Comment: Exactly you will always have single and same instance to access members of that class